# how to take measures against unauthorized access by view-source google chrome

Tags: php

i want take measures against unauthorized access to my resources.

**a.php**

1,in a top of page, a token is made and registed to database.

2,in the middle, src = "./returne.php?token=xyz"
if token is exsisting on DB, return.php execute "readfile()"

3,in the end,  the token is delete from DB(onLoad).

i made code like this first, but the token already didn't exist on DB when access to return.php.

so i made the code with js for deleting the token at step3.
js will execute after php executing.

but function of "view-source" in GOOGLE CHROME doesn't execute js but php is executed.
then the token will be made, but not deleted.

how can i take measures against view-source?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is the way Chrome works [by design](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=4650).

> When you "view source", you're really opening a new tab that opens the page again and displays the source rather than renders the page. Many web pages are dynamic and modify their HTML content (eg. using JavaScript/XMLHttpRequest) so we cannot display the current HTML - this is why a new request is made.

Chrome initializes a new page request, but only displays the HTML without rendering (meaning javascript won't run).

That said, I wouldn't consider a "view-source" as part of any normal user's flow in any web application (unless debugging or trying to reverse engineer).

Ref: https://superuser.com/questions/243967/is-it-possible-to-change-chromes-view-source-behaviour-to-use-the-current-reque

Answer (score 0):

You could take a measure to ensure that the js was executed with the Ping/Pong idea.
Before you execute the php commands have js create

```
    $ping=$pong
```

and in your php code check that ping=pong before continuing.